# ¿Como aplicar correctamente 'expo-task-manager' en mi proyecto mobile?

Tags: javascript, programación-móvil, expo

tengo un proyecto mobile con expo en le cual debo implementar tareas en segundo plano a ciertas horas del día sin que la app este abierta, para ello quiero implementar 'expo-task-manager' pero al momento de importar la libreria y utilizar los metodos que arroja el error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailableAsync' of undefined".

He importado la libreria de tres maneras diferentes y aun asi no me funciona, lo mas extraño es que al revisar el método me muestra la descripción de este, por lo que si lo reconoce:

```
  import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
  import { isAvailableAsync } from 'expo-task-manager';
  import { TaskManager } from 'expo';
```

Instale el modulo de tres maneras distintas y ni aún así funciona:

```
  npx expo install expo-task-manager
  npm install expo-task-manager
  yarn add expo-task-manager
```

aqui les dejo parte de mi codigo donde realizo la importacion y hago el llamado al metodo:

```
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

useEffect(() => {
    const loadBackgroundTasks = async () => {
      try {
        console.info("backgroundTasks init-----------------");
        const res = await TaskManager.isAvailableAsync();
        console.log("TaskManager is available", res);
        console.info("backgroundTasks finish");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("backgroundTasks error", error);
      }
    };
    loadBackgroundTasks();
  }, []);
```